# Keep getting a bad access error in ios when clicking on button

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

SO when I click on a button in my view I get a BAD ACCESS error. I think this is happening because I am creating the view controller and then returning the view to a function that adds said view as a sub view to a table cell.

Like this-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if([self.resultsTuples count] != 0){
    NSDictionary* rowData = self.resultsTuples[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell* tableCell = [self.resultTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
    UIView* cardView = [cardChooser getCardView:rowData];
    [tableCell addSubview:cardView];
    return tableCell;
} else {
    return nil;

}
return nil;
```

}

Everything is rendering correctly - I just have a button, and when I click on it I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Everything seems to be correctly connected in the xib file.

I know this question isn't likely to get a straight answer, but any ideas on where to look for the bug would be helpful.

I also know that this isn't a problem with the function connected to the button because

```
  - (IBAction)map:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"LAT AND LON : %@, %@", self.latitude,self.longitude);
    [MapUtils displayLocationOnMap:self.latitude withLongitude:self.longitude];
    [MapUtils displayDirectionFromCurrentLocationOnMap:self.latitude withLongitude:self.longitude];
}
```

The NSLog is not run before the bad access.

This is the exact error-

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=somePointer)
```

Could this be a memory issue?

This is how I'm returning the view-

```
-(UIView*)getCardView:(NSDictionary*) component{
    return [self getGeneralResultView: component];
```

}

```
-(UIView*)getGeneralResultView:(NSDictionary*)component{
    GeneralResultViewController* generalResultVC = [[GeneralResultViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GeneralSearchResult" bundle:nil];
    generalResultVC.name = someName;
//do other stuff
    return generalResultVC.view;
}
```

I guess something along the lines of - the view controller has been GCed away and there's no button.

Comment: Have you tried adding your view to tableCell.contentView?

Comment: isn't that a read only property?

Comment: nvm - that doesn't seem to work either. I did this - [tableCell.contentView addSubview:cardView];

Comment: No, it is the intended superview to add any subviews to for a cell.

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: so the logger doesn't output anything - where should I be looking for the error beyond the popup?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45030/discussion-between-joel-and-praks5432)

Comment: Why do you need a controller (`GeneralResultViewController`) just to add a subview to the table cell?